# How can I show and hide content with Bootstrap 5 buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have two buttons which will display content when clicked. What I want to do is hide a buttons content when the other button is clicked. For example, clicking button 1 displays the button 1 content. If button 2 is clicked, I would like to first hide the button 1 content before displaying the button 2 content. And vice versa. How can I do this in Bootstrap 5?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button 1
  </button>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button 2
  </button>
</p>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  Button 1 content
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  Button 2 content
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially describing tabbed [Pills](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#pills) behavior. Why not use that?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="m-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#one" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="one" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#two" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="two" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="one">
      Button 1 content
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two">
      Button 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use toggle to show some elements and hide others just with attributes.
You need to use javascript. One option is to use bootstrap api. See [Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#events).
Other way is to use inline event handler for the **onclick** event to achieve what you need.

See the example below. In this case, the onclick event handler for the first button removes the **show** class from collapse2 and viceversa.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse2').classList.remove('show'); })();">
    Button 1
  </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse1').classList.remove('show'); })();">
    Button 2
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  Button 1 content
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  Button 2 content
</div>
```

Comment: Event handlers are a much better strategy than inline scripting.

Comment: What if you have more than 2 buttons, this solution won't work. The content gets stacked on top of each other.