# How can I show and hide content with Bootstrap 5 for more 5 buttons.Without the content gets stacked on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 buttons that display content when I click. I want to be able to hide content when any button is clicked. For example, clicking button 1 displays the button 1 content. If button 5 is clicked, I would first hide the button 1 content before displaying the button 5 content.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984110/5474070) only works if there were two buttons.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse2').classList.remove('show'); })();">
    Button 1
  </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse1').classList.remove('show'); })();">
    Button 2
  </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse2').classList.remove('show'); })();">
    Button 3
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  Button 1 content
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  Button 2 content
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
  Button 3 content
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1):

Not being a professional webdev myself I can empathize with the struggles of making bootstrap do what you'd like

Based on my little experience with it, I think that this might fix your problem

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.collapse').forEach(collapse => {
      collapse.classList.remove('show');
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse2').classList.remove('show'); })();">Button 1</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse1').classList.remove('show'); })();">Button 2</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('collapse2').classList.remove('show'); })();">Button 3</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  Button 1 content
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
  Button 2 content
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
  Button 3 content
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Notice that with this solution there isn't repeated gobs of JavaScript in the markup. It uses an event listener in the script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want [pilled tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#panel-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1" aria-selected="true">Button 1</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab-2" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#panel-2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2" aria-selected="false">Button 2</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab-3" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#panel-3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-3" aria-selected="false">Button 3</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab-4" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#panel-4" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-4" aria-selected="false">Button 4</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab-5" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#panel-5" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-5" aria-selected="false">Button 5</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">Panel 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">Panel 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">Panel 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel-4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">Panel 4</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">Panel 5</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```